# Python: Create New Field in Dataframe if Text in Another Field Contains Exact String

Tags: python, dataframe, text, field, contains

I have the following pandas data frame below.  The column I want to create is highlighted in yellow:

[image]

Below is the business rule I want to implement to create a new column called "Desired Result".

- If the words "series7" appear in the field "Certifications", I want the "Desired Result" field to say "Contact holds series7 designation".

My problem is if the value under "Certifications" field contains more words than just "series7" I am unable to get the result I want.

Below is my code:

```
df_retdesig['Certifications_Flag'] = np.where(df_retdesig['Certifications'].isin(['crpc', 'crps', 'qpfc', 'oka', 'qpa', 'series7']), 'Contact holds series7 designation', '')
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html). Since you also have multiple options you can use `regex=True` (I'm using slightly shorter names so the code will fit nicely):

```
df['new_col'] = np.where(df['old_col'].str.contains('(?:crpc|crps|qpfc|oka|qpa|series7)',
                                                    regex=True),
                        'Contact holds series7 designation', '')
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['crpc', 'crpc afgjg', 'series7', 'asda series7 asd', 'asdf']})
print(df)

 #                      a
 #    0              crpc
 #    1        crpc afgjg
 #    2           series7
 #    3  asda series7 asd
 #    4              asdf

df['b'] = np.where(df['a'].str.contains('(?:crpc|crps|qpfc|oka|qpa|series7)',
                                        regex=True),
                   'Contact holds series7 designation', '')
print(df)

#                     a                                  b
#   0              crpc  Contact holds series7 designation
#   1        crpc afgjg  Contact holds series7 designation
#   2           series7  Contact holds series7 designation
#   3  asda series7 asd  Contact holds series7 designation
#   4              asdf
```

Comment: worked perfectly!  thank you so much ; btw, what does regex do?

Comment: @PineNuts0 That would be hard to explain in a comment. You can google "regular expression".